# C# Ошибка при добавлении второго UserControl

Tags: c#, usercontrol

Создаю новый UserControl. На форме уже находится один контрол, но при перетаскивании из панели элементов на форму нового UserControl, вылазит такая ошибка.
Сборка Any CPU, ничего не менял.

[image: Сама оишбка]

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/b7fkh29k(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: У меня тоже такое было. Я плюнул, и ставил их на форму программно. Потом они вообще с панели исчезли. Потом появились, и я обнаружил, что панель работает корректно